# The browser gets 502 error when to deploy Node.js project on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

My project is a Node.js webapp and I've deployed it on Bluemix by Cloud Foundry Cli. But I always get "502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request." after the deployment.

According to the log console, the app has been started up and runs all right. However, each time when I visit the  route, the log end only has the route change message and the browser just show "**502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.**" without any redirecting to my target app.

Here's part of my log:

> 2017-04-10T20:53:04.90+0800 [RTR/0]      OUT {*my route on blumiex*} -
>   [10/04/2017:12:53:04.906 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 0 67
>   "https://{*my route on blumiex*}/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac
>   OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" 169.53.228.150:57117
>   x_forwarded_for:"9.85.178.221" x_forwarded_proto:"https"
>   vcap_request_id:00b214c1-cdcd-4667-5712-99d12e54ef58
>   response_time:0.002434672 app_id:40174641-3473-4cb7-856f-00ecb90970ee
>   x_global_transaction_id:"3774384181"

I would appreciate if there is some advice.

Comment: Care to share the relevant code?

Comment: What's your app actually serving for the requested `/favicon.ico`?

Comment: @data_henrik which part code do you refer to?

Comment: @nitind I'm not sure. The ./favicon.ico seems to be a default request redirection from the bluemix proxy server.

Comment: @timelyxyz I understand that part. What I'm asking is what is your app actually doing on the other side for that request?

Comment: @nitind Our project's front end has set up a web socket event. So if the deployment is successful, front end would trigger the web socketand the log console would get corresponding ws messages. However, the log only outputs the route change, without any websocket message.

Comment: did you try with an other browser and deleted your cache history

Comment: @jacques Yes, it met the same issue. I event tried on other device, all goes to the same result. I can't get the detailed log of bluemix, it makes it hard to trouble shooting.

Comment: may be you should open a ticket on the bluemix support

Comment: have you explore this part of the documentation: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_troubleshoot.html#ts_group_502

Comment: @jacques Actually my app is not deployed as container. But if no solution found, I will try the container way. Thank you.